# Embedded database configuration from Maven/Spring context

Tags: java, spring, maven, configuration, embedded-database

I want to use the same embedded database from both maven and spring context.
Via Maven Liquibase plugin I'm creating db schema and populate it with data.
Via Spring I'm going to work with the database.
Also I need a way to connect to the database via Intellij IDEA IDE.

In Spring 3 there is an oppotunity to configure embedded database using:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="datasource" type="HSQL"/>
```

In order to create schema and populate the database via Maven Plugin I need configure it as:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <propertyFile>src/main/resources/db/config/${envProfile}-config.properties</propertyFile>
        <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In this case my properties file has the following properties:

```
driver: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
#HSQLDB Embedded in file
url: jdbc:hsqldb:file:src/main/resources/db/hsqldb/dataFile
```

The first question. How can I use the same database using both Spring and Maven context?
As a solution I may configure the database in Spring as usuall dataSource bean - passing it the configuration options from the properties file. But I want to use exactly Spring 3 feature - . If I can connect it in Spring context, so I can connect it via Maven plugin. How can I do it? Why everywhere it is recommended to configure dataSourse as usual bean without  to solve the problem? Why new feature has been added to Spring, but I can use it only from within Spring context and cannot connect to the database from jdbc-based database visual tools?

PS:
It seems embedded HSQL database is all-in-memory (I thought it may be all-in-file) and in-process. As a result, there is no way to create schema and populate it in one process. Finish it. And then try to connect from within another process. Please correct me, if i'm wrong.